# mouseup preventing drop in jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a draggable element, that can be dropped in a div.

```
function trashCan(){
    $('#trashCan').droppable({
        accept: '.tbDocument',
        drop: function(ev, ui) {
            console.log("dropped");
            //justDropped set to true
            justDropped = true;
            var idProcessed = parseInt($(ui.draggable).data('id'));
            var tbl = $(ui.draggable).data('tbl');
            var idPrevious = parseInt($(ui.draggable).data('oldid'));
            var name = $(ui.draggable).data('name');
            var trash = 'Papierkorb';
            var blank = '';
            var projectName = $(this).data('project');
            var subProjectName = $(this).data('subproject');
            setMessageBox(name,blank,trash,idProcessed,tbl,idPrevious);
            deleteMe = true;
            overviewBL.updateIdProcessed(idProcessed,tbl,-1,1);
            $(this).css('background-color', '');
            $(this).effect("highlight", {color: '#97d700'}, 1000);
            $(ui.helper).remove();
            $(ui.draggable).remove();
        },
        over: function(ev,ui){
            $(this).css('background-color', '#97d700');
        },
        out: function(ev,ui){
            $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
        }
    });
```

The function above is called by the draggable element when i start dragging.

```
    html.draggable({
        cursor: "-webkit-grabbing",
        helper: 'clone',
        revertDuration: 500,
        revert: true,
        appendTo: 'body',
        opacity: 1.0,
        start: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#E0E0E0'); 
            ui.helper.css('background-color', '#E0E0E0');
            ui.helper.css('margin', '0');
            ui.helper.css('z-index', '9999');
            trashCan();
            justDropped = false;
        },
        stop: function(event,ui) {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#ffffff');
            //if not dropped on trash
            if (!justDropped){
                overviewGUI.preview(id,tbl);
            }
        }   
    });
```

The Drop is working so far but i want to add some events. Mousedown and Mouseup. 
I would like the Function that creates the droppable div to be called on click on the draggable element. And if it is not dropped I want another function to be loaded, so I implemented the following

```
$(document).on("mousedown", ".tbDocument", function(e) {
    console.log('drag');
    $(this).draggable();
   overviewGUI.createCan();
});

$(document).on("mouseup", ".tbDocument", function(e) {
    console.log('drag');
    overviewGUI.preview($(this).data('id'),$(this).data('tbl'));
});
```

No these to added function are preventing the drop. It is not working if i add the mouseup. Why is that so?

Comment: attaching draggable after the mouse is already down is too late.

Comment: It's the mouseup that is preventing the drop. The Mousedown is not the problem

Comment: @Silve2611 Can you provide MCVE replicating your issue? And only relevant code not all unrelevant one. And btw, i'd say epascarello is right, it should be to late if you didn't already initilaize plugin on it

Comment: At the moment i cannot provide a MCVE. Why does an mouseup event prevent the drop of my element. I don't get it?